# ControlTemplate with changes for every class

Tags: wpf

I have the following ControlTemplate which is the same for all my CustomControls.

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PssFunctionControlBaseHorizontal" TargetType="local:PssFunctionControlBase">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="1">
            <ContentControl x:Name="InnerContent" Template="{StaticResource InnerContentBaseHorizontal}" />
        </Border>
        <Control x:Name="PART_ResizeDecorator" Visibility="Collapsed"
                 Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True"
                     Binding="{Binding EditModeEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PssViewLayoutControl}}}">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_ResizeDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then I use this in a Style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:PssFunctionControlBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource PssFunctionControlBaseHorizontal}" />
</Style>
```

But I want the ContentControl "InnerContent" to change its template with every class.

E.g.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PssFunctionControlSlider}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    ????
</Style>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a separate property of Type `DataTemplate` and bind that to the `InnerContent`.

```
public DataTemplate InnerContentTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(InnerContentTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerContentTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InnerContentTemplate.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerContentTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InnerContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(PssFunctionControlSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Templated bind it in your base template...

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PssFunctionControlBaseHorizontal" TargetType="local:PssFunctionControlBase">
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="1">
        <ContentControl x:Name="InnerContent" Template="{StaticResource InnerContentBaseHorizontal}" ContentTemplate="{TemplatedBinding InnerContentTemplate}"/>
    </Border>
    <Control x:Name="PART_ResizeDecorator" Visibility="Collapsed"
             Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" />
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Value="True"
                 Binding="{Binding EditModeEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PssViewLayoutControl}}}">
        <Setter TargetName="PART_ResizeDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Set that `InnerContentTemplate` from your derived styles...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PssFunctionControlSlider}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
     <Setter Property="InnerContentTemplate" Value="Your Template" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Which binding r gone?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I've changed all Binding to ReleativeSource FindAnchestor and now it works.